# Open file in externall app on Win RT

Tags: windows-8, .net-4.5

How can one open a file in external app on Windows 8 RT? In my case, I'm developing a client for one of the torrent trackers and want to open torrents in uTorrent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it would be useful for someone, the solution can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh779671)